# it seems that this project has not been built yet loop

Tags: c++, codeblocks

I built my project with codeblock and mingw (it a gui interface develloped with wxwidget). The built is finished without problem, but when i try to run it it give me this message :

it seems that this project has not been built yet. do you want to build it now. when i say yes it built it again, when i say no it give me this message :

Checking for existence: P:\Projet test\Build\test.exe
Executing: "P:\Projet test\Build\test.exe"  (in P:\Projet test\Build)
Execution of '"P:\Projet test\Build\test.exe" ' in 'P:\Projet test\Build' failed.

I dont understant what is should do.

This is a screen of my project properties :

[image]

Comment: I don't know what is happening here, but I had a similar error trying to compile a project in VS2013. The problem was that I didn't add the code source to the project, so it was compiling anything. Just to be sure, try to create a new project, copy the code to it and compile.

Comment: I have all source code in the project.